# multiselect value insertion in the database rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, combobox

i have three models that is vendor_info, vendor_packages and packages.
in packages table i have package_name field. the relations between these models are many_to_many.
in vendor_info form i am using multiple select field because different vendors can provide different packages. now i need to save these information in vendor_packages table where i have vendor_info_id and package_id as fields. 
how do i achieve this ?
 this is my multiple select field

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= select_tag "package",
       options_from_collection_for_select(Package.all, :id , :name),
       {:prompt=>"Select Package",:class=>"form-control multiselect"}%>
    </div>
```

Comment: Look at the params you receive from the POST, you should receive a list of selected Package ids (I assume you're also receiving the current vendor id in those params as well). Ensure that any ids in the existing vendor_packages association are in your selected list, and likewise that any ids in your selected list are written to the vendor_packages association.

Comment: Please provide more info: snippets of your controller, the params you receive, etc.